# Plot per year box plots of python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
                    A        B         C  
Date                                                      
2015-04-20 -0.000585 -0.003030  0.000198  
2015-04-21 -0.001334 -0.001330  0.000712  
2015-04-22 -0.000967 -0.000317  0.002388  
2015-04-23 -0.004314 -0.001281  0.002453  
2015-04-24 -0.004910 -0.002032  0.002502 
...
```

and I want a box-plot that refers to the values (A,B,C) of each year (a per year box-plot). I have tried in this this [direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065157/yearly-boxplots-with-pandas) but can not make it fit. My last try is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=mydf.index.values,
                  data=mydf.values,               
                  columns=mydf.columns.values)
df['Year'] = mydf.index.year
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x='Year', y=mydf.index.values)
for item in ax.get_xticklabels():
   item.set_rotation(90)
```

and returns

> ValueError: all arrays must be same length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this way by stacking your `DataFrame`:

```
df_stacked = df.stack().rename('y').reset_index()
sns.boxplot(data=df_stacked,
            x=df_stacked.Date.dt.year,
            y='y'
           )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, helped me to make a little research on some new concepts (`stack`, `rename`, `reset_index`) I didn't met before.